# Why pyautogui clicks on the mouse pointer position and not the defined position?

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

*Below is my code and .click function is clicking on a point where my mouse pointer is . But i need to locate something with a image and need to click that . Anyone have a solution for this ??*

```
import pyautogui

import os

os.system(r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe')

position = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r"join_button.png")

pyautogui.click(position)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the coordinates of the position variable?

Comment: No . The app launches at different positions .  So is there any way to find the coords with a image and find the coords then click that?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late but I am pretty sure you have to use `pyautogui.center(position)` after locating on screen. So, the code would look something like this:

```
import pyautogui

import os

os.system(r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe')

position = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r"join_button.png")
center_pos = pyautogui.center(position)

pyautogui.click(center_pos)
```